# Агрегатные функции для вычисления дохода за два периода

Tags: oracle

Я только начинаю изучение SQL и ещё не очень хорошо с ним разобрался.
Хотелось бы узнать, есть ли способ одним запросом вывести две суммы за два разных периода?
Мой запрос (будет ниже) выводит только пересекающиеся строки в таблицах, и я никак не могу понять, как мне вывеси всё. Пробовал и left join, и full outer join - ничего не помогает. Данные берутся из двух таблиц - Договор и продукт.

В договоре есть:
номер договора (PK), код продукта, дата договора, сумма

В Продукте:
код продукта (РК), наименование продукта, код типа продукта.

```
    SELECT P.PROD_ID AS "Код", 
           P.PROD_NAME   AS "Наименование продукта", 
           SUM(C.TOTAL)  AS "Показатель на 4 квартал 2020 года", 
           SUM(C2.TOTAL) AS "Показатель на 1 квартал 2021 года"
    FROM PRODUCT p
    LEFT JOIN CONTRACT c
    ON P.PROD_ID = C.PROD_ID
    LEFT JOIN CONTRACT c2
    ON P.PROD_ID = C2.PROD_ID
    WHERE C.CONT_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('2020-10-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2020-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    AND C2.CONT_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('2021-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('2021-03-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    AND P.PRTYPE_ID = 1
    GROUP BY P.PROD_ID, P.PROD_NAME, C.TOTAL, C2.TOTAL;
```

У меня этот запрос выводит вот это:

```
Код |Наименование продукта                   |Показатель на 4 квартал 2020 года|Показатель на 1 квартал 2021 года|
----+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------+
3|Фьючерсный контракт на обыкновенные акции  | 120536.69| 69582.29|
```

а должно быть примерно вот так плюс ещё один показатель на квартал.

```
Код |Наименование продукта |Показатель на 4 квартал 2020 года|
----+--------------------------------------------------------+
1|Фьючерсный контракт на обыкновенные акции | 46530.56|
2|Фьючерсный контракт на обыкновенные акции | 55945.35|
3|Фьючерсный контракт на обыкновенные акции | 69582.29|
1|Фьючерсный контракт на обыкновенные акции | 62167|
```

Буду благодарен, если вы сможете подсказать мне.

Comment: Создайте минимальный пример данных на каком-нибудь фиддле, например [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3519d165aa4891f91b88e6815fe5964c).

Comment: У вас комментарий выше вызвал затруднения? Но если вы начинаете изучение SQL, то содавать пример данных вам придётся чаще, чем вы сейчас можете себе представить. Это основа, без которой дальнейшее изучение будет затруднено.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

По всей видимости, стоит задача вывести сумму по двум периодам времени, в данном случае - кварталы. Надо просто транспонировать (повернуть) агрегированный результат.

Пример данных (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ab68328ee3a1a7003948985060417d7c)):

```
create table products (id primary key, name) as
    select rownum, trim (column_value)
    from xmlTable ('"prod1","prod2","prod3"')
/
create table contracts (id primary key, prodid, startdate, total) as
    select rownum, mod (rownum, 3)+1, date'2021-01-01'+rownum-1, 100
    from dual connect by level<=180
/
```

Сам запрос (где `Q` - маска формата для номера квартала):

```
select name, coalesce ("'Q1'", 0) "Q1", coalesce ("'Q2'", 0) "Q2" 
from (
    select p.id, p.name, 'Q'||to_char (c.startdate, 'Q') quarter, sum (c.total) total
    from products p 
    join contracts c on c.prodid = p.id
    group by p.id, p.name, to_char (c.startdate, 'Q'))
pivot (sum (total) for quarter in ('Q1','Q2'))
```

Даст ожидаемый результат:

```
NAME             Q1         Q2
-------- ---------- ----------
prod2          3000       3000
prod3          3000       3000
prod1          3000       3000
```